# exclude php files or a whole directory from codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have some php files in the root directory and a directory containing some php files which I want to exclude from codeigniter. I have this code in htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdomain_name\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(directory_to_exclude)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

When I navigate to example.com/directory_to_exclude I get a list of php files (I'll add an index to prevent listing) but when I try to run any of them it reloads the codeigniter homepage. So how to fix this and how to exclude any php file in the root directory like example.com/test.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your last rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+[^/.]+\.php[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+directory_to_exclude/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+[^/.]+\.php[?\s/] [NC]` will exclude all `.php` files in site root directory.

You shoud use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` because it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

**EDIT:** If this doesn't work then change file permission to `644`. (this actually solved OP's problem)

Comment: Getting Internal Server Error though the file just echo a word for testing no code to generate an error at all

Comment: I have tested this rule on my Apache and there is no error. If you are getting 500 then check your Apache error.log file and post relevant long line here.

Comment: [Sun Nov 26 06:42:42.166799 2017] [:error] [pid 6596:tid 139984422000384] [client IP_ADDRESS:31585] SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File "/home/USER/public_html/c_code/file.php" is writeable by group, referer: https://www.example.com/c_code/

Comment: Keep your php files with `644` with this command `chmod 644 *.php` but probably this is the not the cause of 500 error.